# Enable check box when PDF scroll to last page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to open Term and Condition PDF with iframe. When user scroll to last page, i need to enable check box of Accept.

```
 <div>
    <iframe src="assets/terms.pdf" width="970px" height="370px"></iframe>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled> I Accept
    <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://dev.to/vishesh/how-to-detect-scroll-to-bottom-in-an-iframe-angular-8-js-jquery-8e4

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm article which you mentioned is of displaying HTML in iframe. But in my case PDF is getting displayed in iframe. 

any reference for PDF ?

Comment: @KJ : thanks for your revert, even I was with same assumption. I think now I'm pretty much sure about the feasibility and look for other approach.